# Can Gravatars be a part of the Careers 2.0 PDF export?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Would it be possible to optionally include our Gravatar in the PDF that Careers 2.0 produces? This would be useful for people that use their actual picture as a Gravatar.

In some places, it's customary and expected that a CV contains a picture of the person applying (generally 2x2, but the regular size Gravatar should be close enough in print). Placing it above, or to either side of the location, e-mail and web site information would be sufficient.

That's basically the only thing preventing me from just updating my information at Careers, exporting and sending. I'd *really* love to be able to do that :)

Comment: This seems like a great idea. Looks like, after 4 years, it was never added.